# Amazon Connect Transfer Calls if number is in list

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I am wondering if it's possible to transfer inbound calls that belong to a list.

Let's say I have a list of 10K telephone numbers called List_A.

**EXPECTED Behavior:**

1. If the number is in List _A then it will be transferred to another number.
2. if the number is not in list_A then it will be putted on hold.

Is it possible to code that on Amazon Connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible directly in Connect, but you could setup a DynamoDB with those numbers and then query with a Lambda if the number is on that list in Connect.

There is a very easy how-to create a block list for Connect and I´m sure with some small modifications you could get what you want
https://aws.amazon.com/de/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-deny-list-numbers/